# I tried using this inside jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I realized the `$(this)` worked well outside the AJAX but not within the AJAX, can anyone help look at it to see what is wrong or what I can do?

```js
$(function() {
    $(".add_friend").each(function () {
       var a=$(this).closest('div').find('#user').html();
       $.post("check_following.php", {username:a}, function(resp) {
        if (resp=='following') {
         $(this).hide();
        }     
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: This logic makes me think you are repeating the id `user`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a new function, the context of `this` will change. You have to cache the value somehow. Something like this is what I generally use for the same kind of situation:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".add_friend").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this); // Cache it here.
    var a = $this.closest('div').find('#user').html();
    $.post("check_following.php", {
      username: a
    }, function(resp) {
      if (resp == 'following') {
        $this.hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much, I appreciate you. Much love.

Comment: @atomty You are very much welcome. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick button. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is an scope issue here, every time you put a function inside another one in jQuery the scope is different

in the first level selector $(".add_friend").each(function() {..}) you are referencing to every iteration found for the selector, in this case an element with the class '.add_friend'.

On the second level, inside the ajax call $(this) no longer contains the element reference. You need to put the reference of the first level inside a variable so you can used on the another level scope.

It is also a good idea to use the .text() method instead of .html()
so you get only the text inside the #user element, if you put, lets say an "`<i></i>`" tag inside the #user element, the selector $this.closest('div').find('#user').html(); will return "text `<i></i>`", but if you only need the text every time, it is safer to use .text(), you can use .trim() as well to remove any empy space from the string

```js
$(function() {
    $(".add_friend").each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
       var a= $this.closest('div').find('#user').text().trim();
       $.post("check_following.php", {username:a}, function(resp) {
        if (resp=='following') {
         $this.hide();
        }
        
      });

    });

});
```